# C# - Creating Roles In the Seed Method

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I would like to create two roles for the users. One being a RegularUser and another being an Administrator. Since i'm doing everything code-first, how would I go about creating the two roles, and then assigning a single user to be an admin, all within the seed method (If possible)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you are using the Identity Context, if so then you could just add a class that would do seeding and runs it from Startup.cs/Program.cs depending on what your circumstances are.

In this case `YourContext` should inherit from `IdentityDbContext<IdentityUser>`

```
public class SeedUser
    {
        private readonly YourContext _context;
        private readonly UserManager<IdentityUser> _userManager;
        private readonly RoleManager<IdentityRole> _roleManager;

        public SeedUser(YourContext context, UserManager<IdentityUser> userManager, RoleManager<IdentityRole> roleManager)
        {
            _context = context;
            _userManager = userManager;
            _roleManager = roleManager;
        }
        public async Task SeedAsync()
        {
            if (await _context.Users.CountAsync() == 0)
            {
                var adminUser = new IdentityUser("admin");
                var nonadminUser = new IdentityUser("nonadmin");

                await _userManager.CreateAsync(adminUser, "PWD");
                await _userManager.CreateAsync(nonadminUser, "PWD");

                const string administratorRole = "Administrator";
                await _roleManager.CreateAsync(new IdentityRole(administratorRole));
                await _userManager.AddToRoleAsync(adminUser, administratorRole);
            }
        }
    }
```

The seed code can be then triggered from `Startup.cs` from a method

```
 public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, 
                IHostingEnvironment env,
                ILoggerFactory loggerFactory,
                IEmailLoggerProvider emailLoggerProvider)
            { 
                 new SeedUser()
                         .SeedAsync()
                         .GetAwaiter()
                         .GetResult();
}
```